# How to collocate div elements?

Tags: html

How can I list divs like this:

[click please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtjCl.gif)

I have tried float:left; but failed.

Comment: Please post more about what you've tried including the code.

Comment: Thank you all...
Now it's like that: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JIYK2.gif)

Red bordered div:
    position:relative; width:653px; padding:0 0 0 2px; float:right;

Blue bordered divs:
    float:left; width:300px; margin:13px; border-bottom:1px solid #c2c2c2;

** float:right; for right divs.

You can see that 'Deneme Hizli Haber' titled record is down. Why is it so? Thanks again...

Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Qdhz3/

```
.container {
  width: 100%; 
  border: solid gray 2px; 
  vertical-align: top; 
  overflow: auto;
}

.left {
  float: left; 
  width: 48%; 
  padding: 1px;      
}
.right {
  float: right; 
  width: 48%; 
  padding: 1px;
}

.col {
    background: yellow;
    width: 96%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding; 5px;
    border: solid black 1px;
}


<div class="container"> 
<div class="left">
  <div class="col">
      abc bac abc
      abc
      abc dsds d sdsdsd sdsd
  </div>
    <div class="col">
      fg fg fg
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="col">
      fg fg fg
  </div>
   <div class="col">
       fg fg fg<br />
       ab ab ab
  </div>
  <div class="col">
       fg fg fg<br />
      ab ab <br /> ab
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krishnan1159/R3h57/)

```
<div id="first">
    <div id="one" style="float:left;background-color:#ff0000;height:100px;width:100px;margin:0px 5px;">Venkat</div>
    <div id="two" style="float:left;background-color:#ff0000;height:100px;width:100px;">Venkat</div>
</div>
<div id="second" style="float:left;clear:left;margin:5px;">
    <div id="one" style="float:left;background-color:#ff0000;height:100px;width:100px;">Vinoth</div>
    <div id="two" style="float:left;background-color:#ff0000;height:100px;width:100px;margin:0px 5px;">Vinoth</div>
</div>
<div id="third" style="float:left;clear:left;margin:5px;">
    <div id="one" style="float:left;background-color:#ff0000;height:100px;width:100px;">Ram</div>
 </div>
```